# Let a macro count its invocations

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I've a huge **C** project with a module reading and managing configuration data. If I have to add a new configuration parameter, I'll have to edit several functions, e.g. as pseudo-code:

```
void read_configuration(config *c) {
    read_param("p1", c->p1);
    read_param("p2", c->p2);
    read_param("p3", c->p3);
    /* ... */
}

void dump_configuration(config *c) {
    dump_param("p1", c->p1);
    dump_param("p2", c->p2);
    dump_param("p3", c->p3);
    /* ... */
}
```

Is there a way to ensure by macro **at compile time**, that each location has at least the same count of parameters? I thought of making `dump_param` some kind of macro counting the invocations and then add something like

```
#if nr_read != nr_dump
    #error "You forgot something, idiot!"
#endif
```

at the end of the module. I can't find a method to make the macro count its invocations, though...

Comment: *When* do you want to have this check, at compilation?

Comment: It's difficult to do this at compile-time, though a horrendous hack would be to compare `__LINE__` numbers before and after a packed sequence. The usual C approach to this sort of thing, however, is to generate all of the different cases from a single definition by means of a per-parameter helper macro redefined based on the context and the list in a shared file included multiple times.

Comment: there is a non-standard compiler constant `__COUNTER__`, but there is only one available

Comment: @doynax: I've seen this elsewhere, but our coding style does not allow to do so

Comment: There are some possible duplicates of this question. Maybe the boost preprocessor lib will help you. It has a counter implemented. Maybe you can alter the code to provide you with more counters.

Comment: If you use gcc/gpp, have a look at the predefined `__COUNTER__` macro. Not sure, however, how exactly that behaves for different files.

Comment: Why not unify the functions? have read_configuration and dump_configuration be the same function controlled by a boolean parameter that chooses if you should read or dump the parameters? To not repeat yourself in the function, either macro it, or use function pointers (if like in your example dump_param and read_param have the same prototype).

Comment: I'd consider the existance of this requirement a design flaw. So what about starting over ...?-)

Comment: @alk: I mentioned, that the project is huge and has many many dependencies. You don't start over a project with ~600k lines of code if you can avoid it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the list of parameters is the same in both functions, how about factoring *that* out and avoid any possible mismatch ?

#### Using X-macros

```
#define X_CONFIG_PARAMS(config) \
    X("p1", (config).p1)        \
    X("p2", (config).p2)        \
    X("p3", (config).p3)

void read_configuration(config *c) {
#define X(name, param) read_param(name, &param);
    X_CONFIG_PARAMS(*c)
#undef X
}

void dump_configuration(config *c) {
#define X(name, param) dump_param(name, &param);
    X_CONFIG_PARAMS(*c)
#undef X
}
```

#### Using function pointers

```
void alter_config(config *c, void(*func)(char const *name, Param *param)) {
    func("p1", &c->p1);
    func("p2", &c->p2);
    func("p3", &c->p3);
}

void read_configuration(config *c) {
    alter_config(c, read_param);
}

void dump_configuration(config *c) {
    alter_config(c, dump_param);
}
```

#### Using an array and `offsetof`

```
struct param_info {
    char const *name;
    size_t config_offs;
};

param_info allParams[] = {
    {"p1", offsetof(config, p1)},
    {"p2", offsetof(config, p2)},
    {"p3", offsetof(config, p3)}
};

void read_configuration(config *c) {
    size_t paramCount = sizeof allParams / sizeof *allParams;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < paramCount; ++i) {
        Param *p = (Param*)((char*)config + allParams[i].config_offs);
        read_param(allParams[i].name, p);
    }
}

void dump_configuration(config *c) {
    size_t paramCount = sizeof allParams / sizeof *allParams;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < paramCount; ++i) {
        Param *p = (Param*)((char*)config + allParams[i].config_offs);
        dump_param(allParams[i].name, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first approach seems to be **very** nice!

Answer (score 3):

I would rather let the preprocessor *write* the code in the first place.

It could look something like this:

Define the list of parameters in a separate file, say `parameters.inc`:

```
PARAM (p1)
PARAM (p2)
...
```

Then in the source code locally define the macro `PARAM` as required and let the preprocessor include and expand the contents of `parameters.inc`:

```
void read_configuration(config *c) {
#define PARAM(NAME) read_param(#NAME, c->NAME);
#include "parameters.inc"
#undef PARAM
}

void dump_configuration(config *c) {
#define PARAM(NAME) dump_param(#NAME, c->NAME);
#include "parameters.inc"
#undef PARAM
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this sort of programming by clever macro invocation, though it is certainly a popular and potentially useful trick, can also get completely out of hand and beome an absolute maintenance nightmare.  There are other, possibly better ways.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this at compile time without ugly hacks.

What you could do: add a test to your test suite which replaces the header that contains the `read_param()` and `dump_param()` macros so they generate code which only updates a counter. Then, in the `main()` function of that test, place an assertion that compares both counters and fails if they're not equal.

You do have a test suite and run it at compile time, right? ;-)

However, I do agree with the comment that it's probably better to do this differently. In an approach called "table-driven programming", you turn the macro definition and data definition on their head (that is, you have the `#define` in your .c file and the use of the macro in the header rather than the other way around), you don't have this problem. Poul-Henning Kamp, of FreeBSD fame, explains very well how to that [here](http://phk.freebsd.dk/time/20141116.html).